# Configure Weblogic WS XML Factory

Tags: jakarta-ee, xml-parsing, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am trying to figure out how can I configure DocumentBuilderFactory for Weblogic web services. The reason I need that is to prevent XXE attack (Billion Laughs). In OWASP, there is advice how to change XML Factory:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
```

however I do not know how should I access/configure factory Weblogic is using for WS parsing.

Thanks in advance for your answers